What does Harker mean by his final statement in Bram Stoker's Dracula?
Question contains spoilers for the end of Bram Stoker's Dracula.
On a rewatch of this 1992 adaptation by Francis Ford Coppola 1992, I was struck by the final line uttered by Jonathan Harker, played by Keanu Reeves. Dracula has been slashed and stabbed and has stumbled inside, followed by Mina. The hunters go to follow them, and Harker says:

No, no wait.  Let them go, let them go. Our work is finished here. Hers is just begun.

Within, Dracula is destroyed and Mina - who in this adaptation seems to willingly love the Count - mourns him.
In retrospect, this seems a very peculiar line. Harker has been imprisoned, tortured and almost killed by Dracula, who then goes on to steal away his wife. It feels more likely that he'd be the first to pursue the vampire to ensure his destruction, not be the one who stops the others. And what "work" is he expecting his wife, Mina, to do with Dracula, particularly considering he's been dealt a death blow?

There is a dialog between Mina and Jonathan immediately preceding the line in question. Just as Jonathan is about to deliver a final blow to Dracula, she points a gun at him and asks:


When my time comes, will you do the same to me? Will you?
No.


That makes Jonathan change his mind and let Mina finish Dracula the way she wants. He realizes that, having been bitten by Dracula she is destined to end up like him too and he would have to deal with it somehow. But, if he lets her deal with it her own way now, there is a chance for her to break the curse that links her to Dracula and overcome the vampiric infection. So, he stops his companions by explaining that to them in some vague terms.
